# Integer programming

Tags: integer-programming

Can anyone help me to find the right solution?

How can integer programming be used to ensure that X takes on values 1,3, 5 or any even number less than 100?

In practice we have a integer programming problem involving the variable $X$. We want to force $X$ to have one of the above values. In general, this is accomplished introducing some further variables and constraints.

Comment: What is $X$? Your question is very unclear, please expand.

Comment: X is an integer variable

Comment: Surely this is incomplete.  If all I care about is that $X$ be one of the given values, then just return $1$.    Presumably you want your output to do more than this...like maybe return each possible value with equal probability.  But we really can't guess what you have in mind.

Comment: @lulu I have inserted the problem as stated in the book.

Comment: I'm sure the book explains what $X$ is in greater detail.  If it really is this vague, then, as I said, just take the constant $1$.  That is a possible value, yes?  I doubt this is an acceptable answer, but it doesn't contradict anything you have written.

Comment: The problem is explained as I written here :) Just need to use "either or" logical constraint to get the problem resolved, but I still cannot figure it out.

Comment: Huh?  Where is the actual problem?

Comment: @lulu, the problem seems complete to me, in the context of linear integer-programming.

Comment: @GiovanniResta  Can you explain what it is asking?

Comment: @GiovanniResta: Ahh, I think your answer makes it a bit clearer what was intended.  I still think you had to do a bit of mind-reading, but it's not as much of a stretch as I originally thought.

Comment: @lulu: The OP is looking for how to assert linear constraints such that $X$ is effectively restricted to the set $\{1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, \ldots, 98, 100\}$.

Comment: @RozaR.Poghossian: I think you should be able to reduce Giovanni Resta's answer to two supplementary variables $x_1, x_2$ with a bit of work.

Comment: @GiovanniResta  Ah, thanks.  That makes sense.  I think.

Comment: What is the background of this constraint? I have never encountered a constraint like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual there many different ways to formulate these things. I actually think we can formulate the condition $x \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6,8,10,12,..,100\}$ with fewer variables than using the encoding suggested in the other answer. Probably in practice this will not make much of a difference.

Here is my attempt:
\begin{align}
    & 6 - (1-\delta)M \le x \le  5 + \delta M\\
    & 2y -(1-\delta)M \le x \le 2y+(1-\delta)M \\
    & 1 \le x \le 100 \\
    & x \> \text{integer}\\
    & y \> \text{integer}\\
    & \delta \> \text{binary}
\end{align}

Basically this says:
\begin{align}
  & \delta=0 \implies x\le 5 \\
  & \delta=1 \implies x\ge 6, x = 2y
\end{align}

We can choose $M=100$.

Answer (score 2):

This is just my first idea. Maybe you can refine it in something better, exploiting the fact that the values in between $1$, $3$, $5$ i.e., $2$ and $4$, 
are also allowed because even. In the following I used a technique which should work for arbitrary values.

Substitute your integer variable $X$, wherever it appears, with the sum

$$
x_1+3x_2+5x_3+2x_4
$$

where $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4\ge0$, and $x_1,x_2,x_3\le1$ and the additional constraints

$x_1+x_2+x_3\le 1$, so no more than one value $x_1,x_2,x_3$ can be $1$.

$x_4 \le 50(1-x_1-x_2-x_3)$, because, if none of the $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are 1, then the bound is $x_4\le 50$, otherwise it is like $x_4\le 0$, so $x_4$ it is forced to be $0$.

$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4\ge 1$, at least one value is taken, so $X$ cannot be $0$.

So, if $x_1=1$, the value is 1, if $x_2=1$, the value is $3$, if $x_3=1$ the value is $5$. If $x_4\ge1$ the value of $X$ is an even integer less or equal to $100$.